# Can I import classes from an existing Objective C project into a Swift app

Tags: objective-c, swift, module

I have an existing app and I'd like to share a large number of classes from that app within a new app target. I'd like to leave the existing app as-is and treat it as a module (like a framework), importing it into the new app target which will be written in Swift.

Note this is NOT the simple documented case of adding Swift code to an existing Objective-C application target. I would like to see an example of using the module capability in Xcode to re-use code from an existing target in a new Swift target/module.

The existing app is built as an objective-C application (not a framework)

I would like to build a new app in Swift but use some of the non-gui code from the old app in the Swift app.

I have tried several times to see if there is a way I can import classes from the old iOS-objc app but I'm having difficulties using it in the new Swift app target, methods are not being found

I have turned on modules in this source app.

A) I would ideally like to import classes from the existing App target in the project without refactoring the original app.

B) If that is not possible I could potentially factor out the classes that are common into a separate objective-c framework. This I can get to work thanks to this (http://youtu.be/9us3uijFFpo) , but I'd like to see an example of A) if anyone can crack it. That use case is not covered in Apple's documentation.

But I've searched the web and I can't find any detailed examples of how to do this and my many various attempts to do so have been unsuccessful.  There are plenty of references to adding Swift files into Obj-C apps, but nothing specifically about this kind of case.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: I read that months ago, it does not relate to my specific circumstance which is sharing *between* targets, not the simple case of multi-languages within a single target. I was asking for an example of how my specific problem is solved. That document does not give an example and hence your answer is unhelpful. Try it yourself and if its so simple I accept the downgrade of my question

Comment: Fair enough, but somebody has, and I think this is a completely reasonable question.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the chapter "Mix and Match" of this book from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

It shows you how to import objective class to your swift project. 
In general you have to do some steps:

> - add a "Bridging-Header.h" to your project with name: "YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h"
> - Place your Obc headers somewhere then import ObjcClass.h to your project. I recommend to use "Link to file" instead of "Copy to
>     project"
> - In your bridging-header file, you add #import "ObjcClass.h" to import your ObjcClass header to your swift project
> - You may eventually have to specify Headers location in "Build Setting"

Comment: You say that you want to import code from different target, did you add those codes into your current target?  Click to your class file in left windows of Xcode, it will show the target that this file is imported to.

Comment: Ah, I will try that. I was assuming that if the other target supports 'modules' I'd be able to import it like a framework. In which case I'd only need the header.

Comment: Useful video from App Ninja, it may be simpler to refactor common code into a library module.  http://youtu.be/9us3uijFFpo